# Error in loading landsat 8 images using water package

Tags: r

i am working with water package and when i want to load the image from an specific working directory i am getting this error.

> amg<- loadImage(path = rawimgae, sat = "L8")
>
> Error in list.files(path = path, pattern =
>   paste0("^L[EC]\d+\w+\d+_(b|B|band)",  :
>
> object 'rawimgae' not found

Comment: did you check if your path from "rawimgae" is correct? should be something like "C:\path\to\file\rawimage.tif" also check for escape sequences like `\t`

Comment: all the path is correct but its giving the error

Comment: Can you show us the current value of `rawimgae` Best,